# Neuron function gives same output (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, function, machine-learning

I'm making first neural network. While training I noticed that my function for determining how much a neuron will fire always returns the same value `0.5` . I train my Neural network evolutionary and the first 30 or so generation this bug seems to appear. I have looked in to individual neurons and checked their weights, biases and inputs and then calculated the output manually and the result wasn't `0.5` but it still returned `0.5`. Any help on why this happens would be great.

function:

```
    def output(self,inputs):
        return 1/ (1 + math.exp(-(np.dot(self.weights, inputs) + self.bias)))
```

Here my github with the entire file.

https://github.com/sweeg77/Neural-Network

Comment: Is the code you posted the entirety of your neural network code?  I don't see how we can diagnose a neural net from just that code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, I have added my github with the entire file.

Comment: Please put relevant code in the question, not as external links.